# Как проверять наличие пробела в слове?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть переменная, которая используется для проверки и вывода определённого текста из текстового файла.

```
pkill = '.*? (\\w+):(\\w+)\\b(?!:)' # Вывод Player:Attacker (Kirril:Lexa)
```

Через проверку проверяем наличие данной строки из текстового файла:

```
with open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='rt') as b:
     while True:
         k = b.readline()
         if(re.search(pkill, k)):
             target = re.search(pkill, k).group(1)
             killedby = re.search(pkill, k).group(2)
             await kchannel.send(':crossed_swords: Игрок **' + killedby + '** убил игрока **' + target + '**')
```

Что мне нужно.
Например, в текстовый файл записалось новое значение, которое я получил от сервера:

```
[17:01:SS] Vasya Petrov:Jeka
[17:02:SS] Jeka:Vasya Petrov
[17:03:SS] Ivan:Maks
```

Вывод будет следующий:

```
Игрок Jeka убил игрока Petrov
Игрок Vasya убил игрока Jeka
Игрок Maks убил игрока Ivan
```

Проблема возникает в регулярном выражение. Надо, чтобы вместо: Игрок Jeka убил игрока Petrov / Игрок Vasya убил игрока Jeka, было полное имя Васи (Игрок Vasya Petrov убил игрока Jeka / Игрок Jeka убил игрока Vasya Petrov)

Как правильно построить проверку, чтобы выводился текст и со словами, где присутствует пробел и где его нету.
(Игрок Jeka убил игрока Vasya Petrov
Игрок Vasya Petrov убил игрока Jeka
Игрок Maks убил игрока Ivan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К чему такие сложности? Нужно просто разделить строку по двоеточию:

```
names = k[9:].split(":")
player, attacker = names[0], names[1]
```

Comment: Не выходит: https://prnt.sc/13aymlh , https://pastebin.com/6CWHY7cN

Comment: Таймстэмп тоже в строку входит? Тогда нужно слегка подправить элементарным срезом.

Comment: Да :) В вопросе есть.

Comment: В ответе тоже 

Comment: Всё тот же результат. Или я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: Я изменил код и там не может быть тот же результат.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124597/discussion-between-hoojpop-and-).

Comment: Помогло исправление `k[:9]`, правильным вариантом будет - `k[9:]`.

Comment: А, блин, да, перепутал ☺